# glm direction vector rotation

Tags: opengl, c++, quaternion, glm

I'm working on a flight simulator, but I'm stuck with my airplane orientation. I tried some things but noone worked correctly. This is what I have :

To be able to move it and roll it around himself, I need two vectors, forward and up, and use them to create quaternions I need for the rotation :

```
void Plane::Update()
{
    m_position += ( m_forward * m_speed );

    mat4 translation = translate( mat4( 1.0f ), m_position );

    float angle = dot( vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), m_forward );
    quat direction = angleAxis( acos( angle ), cross( vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), m_forward ) );

    m_matrix = translation * mat4_cast( direction );
}
```

vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) is my model orientation. Note that in this code, I don't have quaternion for rolling the plane, because I first want to have a correct direction.

This works great, what doesn't work is when I want to make him taking off. To do that, I first get the right vector, then use it to create my quaternion with the angle I need, and I apply the rotation to the forward and up vector.

```
void Plane::FlyUp()
{
    vec3 right = cross( m_forward, m_up );

    quat temp = angleAxis( radians( 1.0f ), right );

    m_up = temp * m_up;
    m_up = normalize( m_up );

    m_forward = temp * m_forward;
    m_forward = normalize( m_forward );
}
```

Using debugger and an online vector visualizer, It seems to give me the good vectors, but the plane is rotating weirdly ( in fact, that's not even only rotating, he's scaled too for some reasons... ).

What am I doing/understanding wrong?

Edit :

To be more precise, here is screenshoots of what I have :

[image: What I have]

And what I'm trying to have, whatever the m_forward vector is pointing to :

[image]

Comment: Where FlyUp is called in your code ? I suspect this has to do with function call sequence.

Comment: In the render loop. If the up key is pressed, FlyUp() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug quite likely comes from `angleAxis` requiring a normalized vector (see `quaternion.inl` in the source code). You need to call `normalize()` on the cross product result.

(you might be interested in [my article](http://lolengine.net/blog/2014/02/24/quaternion-from-two-vectors-final) about creating a quaternion from two vectors without using trigonometry functions)

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed half of the problem. Do I have to normalize every vectors that are the result of cross product? I tought cross product of 2 normalized vectors was a normalized vector. Do I have to normalize quaternions too? Or angleAxis output normalized one?

Comment: The length of the cross product of two unit vectors is the `sin()` of the angle they form, so it will be a unit vector only if the two vectors are orthogonal. In general you need to ensure your quaternions are normalised, but in the case of `angleAxis()`  the function takes care of it.